# How to change tab bar tint for multiple tabs in iOS 7

Tags: ios7, uitabbar

I have three sections in my app, each section has different tabs.

I was wandering if there is a way to change the tint on the selected tabs to different colours for each section.

For example,

Section one tabs selected tint colour set to default blue.

Section two tabs selected tint colour set to Green.

Section three tabs selected tint colour set to Red.

I know through storyboard file inspector you can change the global tint but can't seem to find an easy straightforward way for three sections of tabs.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each "tab" is actually the `tabBarItem` of one of your UIViewControllers (the children of the UITabBarController).

So look at the properties of the `tabBarItem`, which is a UITabBarItem. Notice that there is a `selectedImage`, different from the `image` (inherited from UIBarItem). So give each tab bar item an `image` and a `selectedImage`, and give that `selectedImage` the color characteristics you want (and make sure that you derive from it an image whose rendering mode is `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal` so that your color is used, and not, as you say, the tint color).